# Generic constructor with type comparison

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to know if something like this is possible in C#.

Assume I also have a class called "Parent" and two classes that inherit from the "Parent" class called "Child1" and "Child2".

```
///<summary>
/// Constructor for my form.
///</summary>
public FrmMainForm<T>(T thisChild)
{
    if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child2)
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Using the constructor the code to call it could look like this:

```
FrmMainForm thisForm = FrmMainForm<Child1>(childObjectToPassIn);
```

I want to create a constructor using a generic and compare the type of the generic. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both child classes inherit from `Parent` and you're using type-checking anyways then just make the parameter of type `Parent`:

```
///<summary>
/// Constructor for my form.
///</summary>
public FrmMainForm(Parent thisChild)
{
    if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child2)
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

or just add overloads (possibly refactoring any "common" coide into separate methods:

```
///<summary>
/// Constructor for my form.
///</summary>
public FrmMainForm(Child1 thisChild)
{
    // Do something
}

public FrmMainForm(Child2 thisChild)
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: This is what I originally had, I wasn't sure if you could pass an object of 'child' type into a method with a 'Parent' type variable. You can do this?

Comment: @OhaxNuv Yes you can.  It's not a great design, however - better to have `virtual` methods/properties in the parent class and `override` them in the child classes.  Then you aren't tied to specific classes (other then the parent).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a constructor which does that, but you could have a generic factory method which does it:

```
public FrmMainForm Create<T>(T thisChild) where T : Parent
{
    FrmMainForm result = new FrmMainForm();

    if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(thisChild.GetType() == typeof(Child2)
    {
        // Do something else
    }

    // return your form
}
```

If you make the constructor `private`, this would become the only way to construct your form.

That being said, switching on types is almost always a sign of a poor design.  I'd encourage you to rethink *why* you want different behavior based on the two child types, and whether that could be refactored into a single method called on the `Parent` class directly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just for curiosity sake, why is this considered poor design?

Comment: @OhaxNuv Switching on type is brittle, and it usually means you have your logic "upside down" - if you're creating off a base class, it shouldn't matter which "subclass" it is, the behavior should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using reflection to check the runtime type of the object here.  Instead you should be using polymorphism to allow you to treat all of the objects identically, and have them each individually function separately based on their own definitions.

The parent type should define a set of methods/properties that represent the operations that you want to perform on any of those types of objects, each child object can then implement the methods/properties as they need to in order for them to function appropriately for their specific differences.